# Screenflick Audio option in MacBook Pro

Tags: audio, macbook, webcam

```
When after I shut down my MacBook Pro by holding the power button for a few sec, (which I found is bad for the computer, so I will not do anymore) I found that my speaker doesn't play until I plug in and out earphone into the machine.
```

When my speaker is not working like this, and when I am on a random webcam chatting site like chatroulette.com, they can hear the music playing on my iTunes when I choose Screenflick Audio option in the Mic setting. But when the Speaker is working back again, they don't hear the music playing even when I do Screenflick Audio mode.

How can I make it work?

Also, how do you make the chatting partner hear my music playing on my computer while I talk to them (not via my speaker, since it's bad quality).

Answer (score 0):

Simple: **don't power off the computer by holding the power button**. This is, as you mentioned, quite bad for the computer, and if the problem only exists when you shut it down in this fashion, I see no more accurate solution. Just a thought.

Comment: the problem disappears when i shut it down and the speaker is not working

Comment: The problem in question is GONE when I shut it down this fashion, but then another problem arises (speaker not playing)